# How to access SQL server database from an phonegap android app?

Tags: android, sql-server, json, eclipse, cordova

I'm confused with the ways to connect SQL Server database with `Android` `Phonegap` app. I used `PHP` code to query the data.

Is that possible?

My app is not running. It's blank. Can anybody give me a clear example or sample code to work out this..

Comment: Use the Webservice instead of direct making connection with the database in the mobile apps.

Comment: @TGMCians Hey I'm a newbie to this,can you explain in details or any links ,sample project..something!!!

Answer (score 1):

Connecting android to server using PHP is best way ...

First use name value pair

```
        public void registerUser(String email, String password, String mobile) {
    // Building Parameters

           List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keyemail", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keypassword", password));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keymobile", mobile));

    // getting JSON Object


    JsonParser.makeHttpRequest(registerURL,params);


}
```

Use JSON to send the data

```
      public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {




            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();





    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        Log.d("Parser", "IN try parse the string to a JSON object");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

PHP code will get this value and use further

```
  // include db connect class
  require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/db_connect.php';

  // connecting to db
  $db = new DB_CONNECT();

  $response = array();



  $email = $_POST['keyemail'];
  $password= $_POST['keypassword'];
 $phone=$_POST['keymobile'];
 $tag=$_POST['tag'];



$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO TableName (register_email,password,mobile)    VALUES('$email','$password', '$phone')");

if ($result) {
    // successfully updated
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Data Inserted Successfully.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["error_msg"]="Error In Insertion";
}
```

?>

Comment: I might be wrong but this looks like a modified copy and paste from the tutorial in my answer. If you read the tutorial in my answer below it will explain everything to you.

Comment: @Mark Winterbottom but that tutorial explains with mysql,does any problem arises when I'm using ms sql???